# Minimum postgresql + spring + react hardware requirements

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

I have to deploy my postgresql + spring + react fullstack application on premise so cloud is out of the question. It's going to be used by around 15 users at a time. But I have to specify what hardware do I need to run my application. Just to be safe I wanted to ask for 16GB of RAM and 100 GB of storage on ubuntu machine. But my friends says it's way too much.

I have been looking for answer everywhere on the internet but it's like nobody deals with dev ops, everybody just writes applications and that's it. Or they host them on something like heroku.

In summary, what's minimum hardware to run postgresql + spring + react application?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell, this kind of thing comes with experience but I'm sure 4 GB of RAM and 20 GB of disk storage will be enough.

Comment: it would be useful to justify these numbers with some sort of [fermi estimate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_problem)